# 'User' object has no attribute 'is_valid' Django

Tags: python, django

I am making a registration form for users to signup using Django 1.8 and python 3.5

I have created a User(Extending User Model Using a Custom Model Extending AbstractUser)(ie I wanted to add custom fields to the default django's Users table like bio, date of birth etc)

This  is my `mainpage/models.py`

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
```

this is `signup/view.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from mainpage.models import User
def signup(request):
    form1=User(request.POST or None)
    if form1.is_valid():
        form1.save()
    context = {
    "form1": form1,
 }
return render(request, "signup.html",context)
```

**Traceback**

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/signup/

Django Version: 1.8
Python Version: 3.5.4
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'mainpage',
 'signup',
 'login',
 'currency',
 'rest_framework',
 'corsheaders')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "C:\Users\vaibhav2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\vaibhav2\PycharmProjects\MajorProject\src\signup\views.py" in signup
  12.     if form1.is_valid():

Exception Type: AttributeError at /signup/
Exception Value: 'User' object has no attribute 'is_valid'
```

**SOME ADDITIONAL INFO**
I am refering to this blog for creating AbstractUser  https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html#abstractuser

Comment: Are you maybe thinking of the is_valid() method on the form, which verifies that the information submitted is complete and accurate?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/validation/

Comment: I have pointed out my mistake in my question but have no idea how to fix it see the question

Comment: The way to fix it is to define a form. Why is that not clear?

Comment: @DanielRoseman You're a lot more experienced than they are!  This can be tricky for newbies!

Comment: @shutup1 I see that you tried to edit your question to incorporate what I said, but now you have a new question.  That's fine, but you shouldn't edit this question (especially after already accepting my answer).  You can ask a new question (and feel free to link to this one if you think that's necessary)

Comment: Also... said with love... you asked that new question really fast.  Spend some time trying to figure it out yourself.  It will pay off in the long run.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are calling `is_valid` on the `User` object, but that's not a method you've defined on the User (or that exists already on AbstractUser).  If you take a closer look at your tutorial, they're actually calling it on the `UserForm`.  Forms have a built-in `is_valid` method used to make sure all the form data submitted is valid (what valid means can differ based on your use case... maybe you're making sure everything's filled in, or that something's a real email address, or that a date is more than six months in the future).

Your code says:

`form1=User(request.POST or None)
    if form1.is_valid():
        form1.save()`

It looks like you *meant* to define `form1` as a form object (otherwise that's maybe the worst variable name ever).  You probably have something called `UserForm` (or similar) in your `forms.py`.  You'll want to import that, and instantiate it like:

`form1 = UserForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/validation/

(side note:  When you come back to your code in a year, will you remember what `form1` was supposed to mean?  Try to name your variable something that explains itself--`user_form` or something similar)